# Evento blur com próximo campo select

Tags: jquery, formulário

Eu tenho um formulário com todos os campos desativados com exceção do primeiro. Ao preencher o primeiro campo, se o valor existir no banco de dados todos os campos devem ser ativados. Fiz isso utilizando o evento blur do jquery. O problema é que o segundo campo é um select, quando clico nesse campo os mesmos não são ativados, mas se clicar no terceiro campo que é um input=text funciona.
Eu não posso inverter a ordem dos campos.

Segue o código:

```js
$(function(){ 
                  
    $("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").blur( function(){  

    var txt_dd_n_fogo = $("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").val();

    $.post('posicoes/function.php',{txt_dd_n_fogo: txt_dd_n_fogo},function(data){
                          
    if( data!='Não existe ainda!' ){ 
       alert(data);

       $("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").val('');

        $("#txt_dd_marca").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_medida").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_mm").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_data").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_km").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_estado").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_obs").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_img").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#bt_salvar").prop("hidden", true);

        }else{
            $("#txt_dd_marca").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_medida").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_mm").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_data").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_km").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_estado").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_obs").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_img").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#bt_salvar").prop("hidden", false);
        }
                        
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="txt_dd_n_fogo" id="txt_dd_n_fogo" required placeholder="Nº de fogo do pneu">
  
  </div>


<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="txt_dd_marca" id="txt_dd_marca" required disabled>
  <option value="">Marca do pneu</option>
                    <option  value="BRIDGESTONE">BRIDGESTONE</option>
                    <option  value="CENTAURO">CENTAURO</option>
                    <option  value="CONTINENTAL">CONTINENTAL</option>
                    <option  value="FATE">FATE</option>
                    <option  value="FIRESTONE">FIRESTONE</option>
                    <option  value="GOODYEAR">GOODYEAR</option>
                    <option  value="KUMHO">KUMHO</option>
                    <option  value="LANDE">LANDE</option>
                    <option  value="MARSHAL">MARSHAL</option>
                    <option  value="MAGGION">MAGGION</option>
                    <option  value="MASTER">MASTER</option>
                    <option  value="MICHELIN">MICHELIN</option>
                    <option  value="PIRELLI">PIRELLI</option>
                    <option  value="SEIBERLING">SEIBERLING</option>
                    <option  value="TOYO">TOYO</option>
                    <option  value="YOKOHAMA">YOKOHAMA</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="txt_dd_medida" id="txt_dd_medida" required disabled>
    <option value="">Medida do pneu</option>
    <option value="205/75">205/75</option>
    <option value="215/75">215/75</option>
    <option value="215/75.17.5">215/75.17.5</option>
    <option value="215/80">215/80</option>
    <option value="235/75">235/75</option>
    <option value="275/70">275/70</option>
    <option value="275/80">275/80</option>
    <option value="295/80">295/80</option>
    <option value="385/65">385/65</option>
    <option value="750/16">750/16</option>
    <option value="900/20">900/20</option>
    <option value="1000/20 comum">1000/20 comum</option>
    <option value="1000/20 radial">1000/20 radial</option>
    <option value="1100/20">1100/20</option>
    </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
   
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="txt_dd_mm" id="txt_dd_mm" placeholder="Milímetro(Atual)"  disabled>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
   <!-- <label for="txt_de_km">KM</label>  -->
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="txt_dd_km" id="txt_dd_km" placeholder="KM" required disabled>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="txt_dd_estado" id="txt_dd_estado" required disabled>
        <option value="">Estado do pneu</option>
        <option  value="NOVO">NOVO</option>
        
        <option  value="NOVO USADO">NOVO USADO</option>
        <option  value="NOVO CONSERTADO">NOVO CONSERTADO</option>
        <option  value="1ª RESSOLAGEM">1ª RESSOLAGEM</option>
        <option  value="2ª RESSOLAGEM">2ª RESSOLAGEM</option>
        <option  value="3ª RESSOLAGEM">3ª RESSOLAGEM</option>
        <option  value="4ª RESSOLAGEM">4ª RESSOLAGEM</option>
        <option  value="COM AVARIAS">COM AVARIAS</option>
        <option  value="DESCARTADO">DESCARTADO</option>
        <option  value="RESSOLADO CONSERTADO">RESSOLADO CONSERTADO</option>
        <option  value="VULCANIZAR">VULCANIZAR</option>
     </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
 
  <textarea class="form-control" name="txt_dd_obs" id="txt_dd_obs" rows="2" placeholder="Observações"  disabled></textarea>
  </div>

<div class="custom-file">

  <input type="file" name="txt_dd_img" class="custom-file-input" id="txt_dd_img" lang="pt-br" onchange="readURLdd(this);"  disabled>
  
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Escolha uma imagem</label>

</div> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="bt_dd" id="bt_salvar" value="Salvar" hidden>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**O problema, pelo que parece, está aqui:**

```
$("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").blur( function(){
```

Para executar as mesmas funções que você está executando usando o elemento do tipo input, você deve fazer a mesma coisa para elementos do tipo select.

**Por exemplo:**
Note que, abaixo, o elemento é o select.

```
$("select").change(function(){
 var txt_dd_n_fogo = $("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").val();

    $.post('posicoes/function.php',{txt_dd_n_fogo: txt_dd_n_fogo},function(data){

    if( data!='Não existe ainda!' ){ 
       alert(data);

       $("input[name='txt_dd_n_fogo']").val('');

        $("#txt_dd_marca").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_medida").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_mm").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_data").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_km").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_estado").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_obs").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#txt_dd_img").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#bt_salvar").prop("hidden", true);

        }else{
            $("#txt_dd_marca").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_medida").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_mm").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_data").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_km").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_estado").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_obs").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#txt_dd_img").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#bt_salvar").prop("hidden", false);
        }

      });
    });
});

**O ideal, nesse caso, é fazer uma função com o código e colocar
dentro do evento do input e do select.**
```

Comment: Tentei fazer como você disse, mas não funcionou. O primeiro campo é um input=text, é quando perder o foco dele os outros campos devem ser habilitados. O problema é que o segundo campo é um select e quando clico nele os campos não desabilitam.

Comment: Tenta usar outro evento, como por exemplo: click
$('select').on("click change", function(){
//code
});

Comment: Cara, valeu pela ajuda, mas também não funcionou. Tentei criar um botão hidden sobre os todos os campos, até deu certo, mas ao preencher o campo nº de fogo novamente ele não executa mais a função de verificação. Precisa ficar bem amarrado, caso o usuário digite um nº que já existe os campos precisam ficar desabilitados.